# Create Expression from a string containing a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm looking for a way to create an expression from a string containg a Linq expression itself.

Assume the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public Address[] Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

A simple expression can be generated with the following code:

```
var expression = @"x.Name";
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");
var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);
```

The sample below will return `Name 1` as expected:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var personsCollection = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "Name 1", FirstName = "Firstname 1", Address = new Address { City = "City 1" } },
        new Person { Name = "Name 2", FirstName = "Firstname 2", Address = new Address { City = "City 2" } }
    };

    var expression = @"x.Name";
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");
    var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);

    var result = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(personsCollection[0]);
}
```

Now, assume that I change the expression to project a `List<T>`.
The expression will than be: `var expression = @"x.Address.Select(dest => new { MyCity = dest.City })";`

Using this is the sample code above throws the following exception: `"Unknown identifier 'dest'"`

Any idea on how this can be solved?

Comment: I think you provided some incomplete code. Please start with a string variable containing the sample string and show the complete code that is used for your working / not working transformation.

Comment: I've completely rewritten the code. Can you have a look?

Comment: Way back when you had https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library and nowadays you could use Roslyn to compile this code into a delegate, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have an object which I want to transform at runtime.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not tied to `DynamicLinq`. Mind providing an example with Roslyn?

Comment: Besides the incorrect syntax, Dynamic LINQ does not support nested `Select`.

Comment: Hmm, too bad as this would have been great :-) Are there any other solutions to the problem I'm facing?

Comment: Branch from System.Linq.Dynamic and extend the parser for nested lambda support? :)

Comment: That's obvious but maybe there are other technologies that can be used where I'm not aware off.